# blake2 with laravel. call to undefined function blake2()

Tags: php, encryption, laravel-4

I am trying to use blake2 for hashing user data.

The other dev on our team was able to get it working on his local environment, and on our development server, but i cannot seem to get it working in my local env.

i added extension=blake2.so to my php.ini file. I've also run through the steps as outlined in the read me of the blake2 github.

Here is the function

```
protected static function hashField($field)
{
    $key = Config::get('app.key');

    return blake2($field, 64, $key);
}
```

This is in the BaseModel. 
I wrote another function to encrypt same said user data in an encryptable trait file, and this is wear i am calling my hashField function.

I am calling use BaseModel in my Encrytpable trait file:

```
<?php

namespace Encryption;

use Crypt;

use BaseModel;

trait Encryptable

{
    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        $value = parent::getAttribute($key);

        if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable)) {
            $value = Crypt::decrypt($value);
        }

        return $value;
    }

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        $hashedKey = str_replace('encrypted', 'hashed', $key);

        if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable) && in_array($hashedKey, $this->hashable)) {
            $hashedValue = BaseModel::hashField($value);
            $value = Crypt::encrypt($value);
        }

        isset($hashedValue) ? parent::setAttribute($hashedKey, $hashedValue) : null;

        return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
}
```

Here I define the hashable columns in the user model:

```
protected $hashable =[
    'hashed_first_name',
    'hashed_last_name',
    'hashed_address_street',
    'hashed_address_apt',
    'hashed_address_city',
    'hashed_address_state',
    'hashed_address_zip',
    'hashed_dob'

];
```

I am running php 7.1 and laravel 4.2.
Any ideas? Ive been stuck for quite a while. Thanks!

Comment: Did you reload apache/IIS/FCGI/FPM after modifying the config? Did you ask your coworker they got it to work?

Comment: Unless you have a strong reason for using blake2 (typically performance), I'd go with the built in HMAC-SHA-2 functions, avoiding the complexity of using an extension module.

Comment: @Sammitch yes I did reload, and yeah he helped me with it all afternoon and we couldn't get it working.